# divs not working correctly

Tags: css

This problem is a little weird (as I need to do this way, since I din't find any another good way).

I have three divs inside a "big div".

The main div is called:

```
<div class="produtos-item">
```

And inside this div I have three another divs

```
<div class="item">
```

So what I need?

Imagine a store (e-commerce). I have 3 products (item).

```
PRODUCT-1 PRODUCT-2 PRODUCT-3
------------------------------
THIS LINE
PRODUCT-4 PRODUCT-5 PRODUCT-6
```

I need to insert a line between the divs. BUT if I set the div .item with no height will break the layout. See the screenshot.

[image]

As you can see, this black circle was the product. But since there is no fixed height and I can't set this (because the title can be bigger), it will break the layout. If I can "call" the main div (produtos-item), I can fix this thing.

Do you know any solution? :(

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WRGba/ [edited May, 10]

Comment: if the divs are breaking it's not should be because of their heights, it's happening because of their width. maybe when you're using some display quirks that mess up their whole size.
see my exmaple: http://jsfiddle.net/Vgafb/

Comment: also, it's not a wordpress question, I edited the tag out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `display:inline-block;` on them (`zoom:1;*display:inline;` for IE6, IE7 compatibility)

Also, a jsFiddle couldn't hurt!

Using @Shebo's example from above:

Not working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vgafb/3/)

Working example: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vgafb/1/)**

Comment: Hi Stefan V., sorry about jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WRGba/ you can check out the PHP and CSS here :)

Comment: Ok, so I changed the CSS to your solution, but is still not working :( `#produtos {
 width: 575px;
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 25px;
}
#produtos .item {
 width: 170px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}`

Comment: If you have the display:inline-block in your CSS you should remove the float:left